# Updating Name of Self hosted gateway in Azure APIM service

Tags: azure, api, azure-api-management, azure-rm-template, apim

I wish to change the name of the Azure APIM Self hosted gateway, however I am unable to so from the Azure portal nor do I get anu option to update the Name. I wish to know if there is any way that we can update it using Azure Powershell or CLI.

Feel free to ask me for more info.

Thank you.

1. I tried to change the Name from the Az Portal but I do not see any such option to modify the nane there.
2. I updated the Name of Self hosted gateway in the ARM template and deployed it but that didnt work. It just added a new SHG with the updated name and kept the old one (the one I want to modify) as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to change/rename the APIM self-hosted gateway name once it is created. You need to create a new gateway with new name and delete the old one.